# Storing a file in database with huge content

Tags: sql-server, database

I tried a lot with the problem stated below, couldn't get an answer.
I have a file with very huge content of texts up to 600 MB, i want to store it in a database. According to what I saw in http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_datatypes.asp, i used 'text' datatype in which up to 2 GB can be stored. But still when i retrieve back, I'm getting truncated file contents.
It looks simillar to-

```
create table academics (
  semester int not null,
  subject varchar (50),
  experience text,  
  primary key (semester)
);
```

experience gets its value from a file with large contents.
Which datatype can I use for the same?

Comment: Why do you want to store a 600 MiB file inside a database?

Comment: Using `varchar(max)` or `varbinary(max)` would be better, but `text` would work as it's the older version of `varchar(max)`. As it's not the data type that is wrong, it has to be your code for reading the data that is wrong. How do you retrieve it back?

Comment: How do you retrieve the file? SQL Server has no problem with large BLOBs, although using the FILESTREAM/FileTable feature offers far better performance as it stores the file externally and allows you to open a stream on it.

Answer (score 0):

Well, be careful with `text`. As stated [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx):

> ntext , text, and image data types will be removed in a future version
>   of Microsoft SQL Server. Avoid using these data types in new
>   development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use
>   them. Use nvarchar(max), varchar(max), and varbinary(max) instead.

Also, for such a large files you can consider using the [FileTables](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff929144.aspx)
if you're using `SQL Server 2012+`

Comment: Or create a database with the FILESTREAM option for SQL Server 2008+. Essentially, all supported SQL Server versions support external storage for BLOBs.

Comment: oh, thank you for the warning, its working with varchar(max) thank you :)